# OpenTok Video Call Issue when application goes from background state to foreground

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, opentok, tokbox

I have done video calling using OpenTok (Tokbox Sample for video calling among multiple users). I am facing a random issue in my application when my application enters in background mode and again application is sent to foreground.

Session remains connected but the video will not be displayed to other users(Black screen is displayed).

I have enabled publishvideo in publisher and subscribe to video for currentsubscriber.
    `_publisher.publishVideo = YES;
    _currentSubscriber.subscribeToVideo = YES;`

Is there any way to fix this issue.

Any help is appreciable.

Comment: https://forums.tokbox.com/ios/resume-video-from-background-to-foreground-t41832  Check if this was fixed in the latest build?

Comment: Any update on this issue?

Answer (score 1):

- Click on Capabilities and turn on Background Modes -> Tern On -Audio,AirPlay,and picture. it will work fine.